# Is there any point where wolves are useful?

Tags: gladius

In Gladius for XBox, we're playing through Nordagh.  It seems like our opponent wolves are fairly tough, so we got a wolf of our own.  To put it bluntly, he's awful.  Lacking most equipment slots, we outfitted him with a collar of force (the stupid thing came with a collar of rage) to up his power.

Frankly, we are unimpressed.  There's really nothing he can do that a berserker couldn't do better, and most of the battles we've found that require non-humans would accept a berserker just as readily as a wolf.

Is there any point in the game where wolves are actually useful?

Comment: Tag added. Xbox? Or xbox360?

Comment: @Raven, original Xbox; it's a previous-gen game (PS2, Xbox, GameCube).

Comment: Okay, just double checking. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolves are not very helpful by themselves. However, when they are in a pack they are a little better.

With Pack Courage they get increased movement and initiative when near other wolves. With Pack Mentality 1 all wolves get a free attack on a targeted opponent with a critical hit, and with Pack Mentality 2 all wolves get a free attack on a targeted opponent with a successful hit.

They can be fairly strong with late-game skills like Riposte, Pull Down, Shred Throat, and Lupus Call.

I really don't think they are worth permanent spots in schools but they are terrible alone.